# MySQL's Update command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables(A and B)

- Table A has id,project_id,enabled columns
- Table B has id,project_id,name,description,note,created_on columns

Lets say in A  table we have only 1 project (id = 11) that has enabled as true and so I treat project id 11 as the parent project

In table B, we have the details of Project 11

What I am trying to do is, if the name or description or note changes in Table B for project 11, in a single query I would like to update rest of all the projects with project 11's changed values.

Comment: If all the projects in table B that relate to project 11 in table A have some shared data: Why is that data copied across each project in table B instead of being stored once in table A?

Answer (score 0):

If the other records with project_id=11 are in the same table, you can simply run:

```
Update tblB set description ='...', name ='...' where project_id = 11
```

If they are in different table, you can use a trigger set to be executed on update of the tblB

Comment: How to get the project name,description dynamically from the project itself?